# LaTeX problem with the fancyheader package

Tags: header-footer, packages, fancyhdr, texmaker, pagestyle

Relatively new LaTeX-user here. I have been running into a lot of problems with the fancyhdr package. The fancyhdr commands do not seem as if they are registering at all but the code runs into no errors. In addition to this, changes I make to text like my title or anywhere else in my document do not appear. Yet when I omit the line that imports fancyhdr, the change I made to the title of the page (sample title to Yolo) suddenly appears and everything works again (except I still have no header D':
).

I attached the exact code I have below in which nothing is changing (the title does not change to "Yolo" and the header does not appear with the fancyhdr package). I am looking for some way to get fancyhdr to work but I have been unable to resolve it. Searching online, I feel like this could be a \pagestyle problem but I am unsure how to rearrange my code in order to completely fix this.

I am currently using Texmaker to edit and code in LaTeX.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \righthyphenmin12
    \lefthyphenmin12
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\MakeUppercase{title should go here}}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    \Huge\textbf{Yolo}\\
    \Large\textbf{sample subtitle}\\[4mm]
    \vfill

    \line(1,0){400}\\
    \Huge\textbf{sample title}\\[3mm]
    \Large\textbf{- sample subtitle -}\\[4mm]
    \line(1,0){400}\\
    \vfill
    Professor: Chuck E Cheese\\
    University of Potatoes\\
    September 12, Fall 2020\\
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3tEW.png
```

Comment: Try pages without the titlepage env, as filler text use can use `\kant` from the `kantlipsum ` package. The titlepage is likely to actively disable all headers and footers on that page

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.